# Opening a rsl file in python

Tags: python, io

I want to open a .rsl file(testing.rsl in this case) in python and load the contents into grid FS.When I simply try to open it it gives me an error stating:

```
'Cannot encode object: <open file 'testing.rsl', mode 'rb' at 0x000000000BA27420>'
```

When i do this: `RSL=open('testing.rsl','rb')`

Can anyone please help me encode it in python?

Comment: What environment are you using? Python on Windows is picky about 'rb'. Is it really a binary file?

Answer (score 0):

The file may not be in binary form (as required by the `'b'` mode). Try with:

```
open('testing.rsl','r')
```